# Consume Flask-generated JSON in Excel PowerQuery

Tags: json, excel, flask, powerbi, powerquery

The following MWE Flask app produces valid JSON. The JSON is parsed correctly from a file, but produces the error `DataFormat.Error: We reached the end of the buffer` when invoked directly from a web service. Why? And how can the error be avoided?

To reproduce:

1. Minimal working example:

   Save the code below as mwe.py; set `FLASK_APP=mwe.py`; execute `flask run`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/users/<user_id>')
def user(user_id):
    return {"user_id": user_id, "answer": [
        {"A": 1, "B": 2},
        {"A": 11, "B": 12},
        {"A": 21, "B": 22},
    ]}
```

2. Create the resulting JSON, e.g. using `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/foo -o c:\temp\foo.json`.

   Now create an Excel PowerQuery that reads the JSON file. To do that, use Data, Get Data, From Other Sources, Blank Query, and paste the code below (possibly adjusting the path). The file is imported without errors:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\foo.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "answer")),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"A", "B"}, {"Value.A", "Value.B"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Value1", each true)
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

3. Now replace the first line of the PowerQuery pipeline with the web service. Now we get an error. Why?

   This still produces the correct table, but the error is visible in the "Queries and Connections" panel.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/foo")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "answer")),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"A", "B"}, {"Value.A", "Value.B"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Value1", each true)
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Comment: It looks like the Content-Length is not computed correctly. Could that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what is happening, but I was able to sidestep the error by:

1. producing compact output JSON
2. explicitly processing only the first line of JSON

Notice the `Source{0}` in the second step of the PowerQuery M code, which selects the first line from `Lines`:

```
let
    Source = Lines.FromBinary(Web.Contents("http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/foo")),
    json = Json.Document(Source{0}),
    as_table = Record.ToTable(json),
    answers = Table.SelectRows(as_table, each ([Name] = "answer")),
    expanded = Table.ExpandListColumn(answers, "Value"),
    finally = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(expanded, "Value", {"A", "B"}, {"Value.A", "Value.B"})
in
    finally
```

There are several answers on SO on how to produce minified JSON from Flask. Below is what I thought was the cleanest:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/users/<user_id>')
def user(user_id):
    "test for reading json in Excel PowerQuery"
    data = {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "len": len(user_id),
        "answer": [
            {"A": 1, "B": 2},
            {"A": 11, "B": 12},
            {"A": 21, "B": 22},
        ]
    }
    return Response(json.dumps(data), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

The `Content-Type` turned out to be a red herring, but it is a good idea to pass the correct `mimetype` anyway.